# How to put urlTemplate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

How can I get the innerHtml from a template html file?

Like `mainform.innerHtml = 'template.html'`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myfunction = function () {
        var text_1 = document.getElementById('text_1').value;
        var mainform = document.getElementById('mainform');
        if (text_1 == 's') {
            mainform.innerHTML = '<p>sala</p>'
        }
        else {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can try ngInclude https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: break that habit of mixing Angular and JQuery like this as soon as you possibly can.

Comment: even if you get the answer... this is not the correct way of doing things in angular.... learn angular way of doing things

Comment: @entre do you mean using ngInclude has disadvantages. If so even let me know other ways to do the same thing.

Comment: @Harsh, that was reply to the question and nothing to do with your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this http://plnkr.co/edit/V3uNa24QkSj6XRODB3R0?p=preview

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="changeTemplate('template1.html')">Template 1</button>
    <button ng-click="changeTemplate('template2.html')">Template 2</button>
    <div ng-include="template"></div>
 </body>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.template = 'template1.html';

  $scope.changeTemplate = function(template){
    $scope.template = template;
  }
});
```

template1.html

```
<div>Template 1</div>
```